# y axis label tick values are random

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the CPU utilization of the linux VM by capturing the stats from vmstat command. I have saved the data in a file and I am trying to plot the user, system and idle cpu %.

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import axis
from matplotlib.axis import Axis

f, a = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
data = [x.strip() for x in open('vm_stat.out', 'r')]

time = [' '.join(re.split('\s+', data[x])[1:4]) for x in range(0, len(data), 2)]

user_cpu = [re.split('\s+', data[x])[12] for x in range(1, len(data)+1, 2)]

system_cpu = [re.split('\s+', data[x])[13] for x in range(1, len(data)+1, 2)]

idle_cpu = [re.split('\s+', data[x])[14] for x in range(1, len(data)+1, 2)]

plt.title("CPU utilization")

a.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))

a.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))

a.plot(time, user_cpu, label = 'User %', color = 'r')

a.plot(time, system_cpu, label = 'System %', color = 'b')

a.plot(time, idle_cpu, label = 'Idle %', color = 'g')

plt.ylim(0,100)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0,100,10))

plt.show()
```

When I see the plot presented, I observe that the y axis label values are not starting from 0 but rather starting from 11 and it displays random values.
What I need is the y axis tick labels should be plotted from 0 to 100 in steps of 10.

Comment: At a guess - your data are strings, convert them to either integers or floats

Comment: Thanks David, after making explicit conversion to int it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That shoud work:

```
a.set_yticks(range(0,110,10))
```